# New order Status Field Blank - All orders have no status

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, order-status

I am having some problems with the New Order Status in Magento CE 1.9.0.1.

When I try to set the new order status for every payment method. The dropdown in blank.

**Worldpay**

[image]

**Check / Money Order**
[image: Check]

This has the effect of all orders except pending payment having a blank order status.

[image]

I have no idea how to sort this issue can anyone give me some advice.

I can see all order statuses in the admin
[image]

Comment: Are the statuses assigned to state codes? Can't tell from the screenshot... it would be indicated in the right-most columns in the grid.

Comment: Thanks @davidalger that did it. I didn't notice that they were missing from this install. Thank you!

Comment: Super, glad to hear it! Just posted this as an answer since it worked as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

For the list of statuses to be populated in the setting drop-downs the statuses must be assigned to states. Assign each of the statuses to a state and they will show up in the list of dropdown values. This is what the grid should look like once this is done:

[image]